# Googlemaps showing "offmap" area when GMSCameraPosition set too far north

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am positioning a GMSMapView using `GMSCameraPosition` like this:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:myLat longitude:myLon zoom:0.0f]; 
mapView = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:myScreenRect camera:camera];
```

But if the latitude (myLat) is too high (too far north) and the zoom is fixed to 0, then the map shows a grey-ish "offmap" area at the top, as per the image below.

Does anyone know how to adjust the latitude value (sufficiently downwards) so that this "offmap" area does not show, while still keeping zoom = 0?

I'm using the iOS Googlemaps SDK.

Thanks in advance.

[image]